# Using Helm on Jenkins VM

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use helm to deploy an chart on a Jenkins freestyle item, the helm command isn't recognised . Jenkins returns -> helm: not found. I have searched through the plugins and I can't find a plugin for helm. Anyone know how to install helm on Jenkins?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, AFAIK there is no such helm jenkins plugin available. But you can have a docker slave agent which has helm installed and use that deploy helm charts on a cluster. [How to Setup Docker containers as Build Slaves for Jenkins?](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/) is a good starting point. While configuring a docker slave as given in the link you can use the docker image [jnlp-slave-k8s-helm](https://github.com/yonadev/jnlp-slave-k8s-helm) which has both helm and k8s client installed. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please share more information about your environment. You are using Google Compute Engine or Google Kubernetes Engine? Did you deploy jenkins on Kubernetes, using Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins or nor of them? Also could you provide versions of kubernetes, jenkins, etc.